# Remove array key prefix recursively

Tags: php, arrays, recursion

I have an array in the following format (each child array has parent's key as a prefix):

```
$input = array(
    'seo_text' => array(
        'seo_text_title'       => '',
        'seo_text_description' => '',
        'seo_text_button'      => array(
            'seo_text_button_text' => '',
            'seo_text_button_url'  => '',
            'seo_text_button_new_tab_enabled' => '',
        ),
    ),
);
```

I want to convert it into the following format:

```
$input = array(
    'seo_text' => array(
        'title'       => '',
        'description' => '',
        'button'      => array(
            'text' => '',
            'url'  => '',
            'new_tab_enabled' => '',
        ),
    ),
);
```

I'm trying to write a recursive function, but it's not working the way it's suppose to be working.

Comment: At least show us what you tried. Please go read [ask].

Comment: what did you try?

Comment: your problem is reasonable but this platform is not a free source code provider. what have you tried? show some code

Comment: The least we can give is necessary topics to make your logic. See these,
 [Key](http://php.net/manual/en/function.key.php), [str_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A solution:

```
function removeKeyPrefix(array $array, string $prefix = ''): array
{
    $newArray = [];
    $prefixLength = strlen($prefix);

    foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
        if (substr($key, 0, $prefixLength) === $prefix) {
            $newKey = substr($key, $prefixLength);
        } else {
            $newKey = $key;
        }

        $newArray[$newKey] = is_array($value) ? removeKeyPrefix($value, $key.'_') : $value;
    }

    return $newArray;
}

$input = removeKeyPrefix($input);
```

[Online demo on 3v4l](https://3v4l.org/Z5cvQ)

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude: indeed, but the only problem is that it doesn't work.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte OMG! It has good taste, but I don't test it to know if it's working or not. However, seems good typed and the code have sense, I will not remove the upvote because it's probably not working for this case, but other users can see this code and improve his.

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude: few (but important) things are missing: give a default empty value to the prefix,  call the function with the current key in the loop, test if the key is empty and eventually an integer before defining the prefix.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte Fixed the code. Check it please.

Answer (score 2):

```
function sanitizeKeys(array $items, $previousKey = '') : array
{
    $previousKey .= "_";

    return array_reduce(
        array_keys($items),
        function($result, $key) use ($previousKey, $items) {
            $newKey = (0 === strpos($key, $previousKey)) ? substr_replace($key, '', 0, strlen($previousKey)) : $key;

            $result[$newKey] = is_array($items[$key]) ? sanitizeKeys($items[$key], $key) : $items[$key];

            return $result;
        }, []
    );
};

sanitizeKeys($input);
```

Comment: Actually, the only correct answer (the only person that has read the requirements).

Answer (score 1):

Make a function to change last occurrence in the slug

```
function fun($array,$slug){
  foreach($array as $key=>$val){
    $last = end(explode($slug,$key));

    if(is_array($val)){
      $val = fun($val,$key."_");  
    }
    $array[$last] = $val;
    unset($array[$key]);
  }
  return $array;
}
$input["seo_text"] = fun($input["seo_text"],"seo_text_");
print_r($input);
```

Live demo : https://eval.in/934155

Output is

```
Array
(
    [seo_text] => Array
        (
            [title] => 
            [description] => 
            [button] => Array
                (
                    [text] => 
                    [url] => 
                    [new_tab_enabled] => 
                )

        )

)
```

For if you have many element in second level use `foreach` to call function like below

```
foreach($input as $key=>$val){
  $input[$key] = fun($val,$key."_");
}
print_r($input);
```

https://eval.in/934156

Comment: Interesting, but the last key must be `new_tab_enabled` and not `enabled`.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte : You are right, I have updated my answer.

Comment: Also the first key must be `seo_text` and not `text`. sorry.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte: There is no change in function just we can call in another way. I just called like `$input["seo_text"] = fun($input["seo_text"],"seo_text_");
print_r($input);`